# Menger's theorem and how many pairwise-edge disjoint paths?

Tags: graph-theory

In a proof, I came across this statement:

```
 By Menger's Theorem, for each $x,y$ there are $k'(G)$ 
 pairwise edge-disjoint $x,y$ path, where $k'(G)$ is the minimum size 
 of a disconnecting set of edges.
```

Why is this true? It was not proven, but stated like it was supposed to be obvious. (It's not to me.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an obvious theorem, but it is quite well known. [Here](http://www.math.unm.edu/~loring/links/graph_s05/Menger.pdf) is a one proof.

Comment: Where am I looking? I don't see the theorem.

Comment: Click on the word "Here" in my answer. It is a hyper link to the proof.

Comment: That is a proof of Menger's theorem. That is not what I wanted.

Comment: Whoops, I thought you didn't know Menger's Theorem. This sounds like Whitney's Theorem. I am not finding much online about it at the moment. Maybe you will have more luck searching for it?